# Unable to find field "username" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara, rack

I'm trying to test a simple login form using cucumber / rspec / capybara. But I'm having trouble detecting elements on the page and doing any sort of test.

Unable to find field "username" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

**Feature File**

```html
Feature: Login
    
    Scenario: correct login credentials
        Given I am on the admin_login page
        When I fill in "username" with "thomas"
```

**ENV**

```html
require 'capybara'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'rack'
require_relative '../../config'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application


class Sinatra::ApplicationWorld
    include RSpec::Expectations
    include RSpec::Matchers
    include Capybara::DSL
end

World do 
    Sinatra::ApplicationWorld.new
end
```

**WEB STEP**

```html
When /^(?:|I )fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/ do |field, value, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    fill_in(field,visible: false, :with => value)
  end
end
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In To Pied Piper</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form role="form" action="/admin/login" method="post" label="form">
                                <fieldset label ="form" >
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       
                                        <input label="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username" type="text" value="<%= params[:username] %>" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="<%= params[:password]%>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a></button>
                                    <button><a href="/" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Return to Main Site</a></button> 
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: 1. Why are you setting `ignore_hidden_elements = false`? That's terrible practice when testing an app, and you can't fill_in non-visible fields even if you pass `visible: false` to fill_in  2.  Is that the HTML you think makes up the page, or is that the HTML returned by `page.html` before you attempt to fill in the field?  Also `label` is not a valid attribute for an `input` element, so what's that doing there?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with my rails appliction and the way I solved it was by giving an id to that field

```
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control',id:"name" %>
```